# Reading material suggestion for history of Newton's laws of motion

Tags: physics, reference-request, classical-mechanics

I intend to review the different concepts related to laws of motion floating around the publication of *Principia* and hopefully would like to comment on these (It's an essay project).

I've gathered couple of books for this purpose, mostly the usual suspects(Galileo's *Two New Sciences*, Newton's *Principia*, Mach's *Science of Mechanics*, Dugas's *History of Mechanics*, Chandrashekhar's *Newton's Principia for Common Readers*, Maxwell's *Matter and Motion*, and a host of common classical mechanics books like Landau, Marion, Summerfield, Taylor, etc. which usually comment on the logical structure of these three laws plus gravitation).

But it would have been really nice to find some articles which directly discuss Newton's laws from philosophical and historical point of views. Searching in Google Scholar got me a paper which discusses Newton's laws with Kant's.

So I really need some references for my project.

Comment: See references in the answers to How did Newton establish the conservation laws in the Principia?
http://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2345/how-did-newton-establish-the-conservation-laws-in-the-principia/2348#2348 and What was the vis viva controversy, including its philosophical aspects?
http://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/596/what-was-the-vis-viva-controversy-including-its-philosophical-aspects/598#598

Comment: I.Bernard Cohen, [The Newtonian Revolution](https://books.google.it/books?id=vKrTt8JvQakC&printsec=frontcover) (1983).

Comment: You can see also : Andrew Janiak, [Newton as Philosopher](https://books.google.it/books?id=dOHbSAAACAAJ) (2010) and Andrew Janiak & Eric Schliesser (editors), [Interpreting Newton: Critical Essays](https://books.google.it/books?id=r5IskjtmGJoC&printsec=frontcover) (2012).

Comment: You can try also with : Jessica Wilson, [Newtonian Forces](http://individual.utoronto.ca/jmwilson/Wilson-Newtonian-Forces.pdf) (2007) and I.Bernard Cohen & George Smith (editors) [The Cambridge Companion to Newton](https://books.google.it/books?id=3wIzvqzfUXkC&printsec=frontcover) (2002).

Comment: I highly recommend Max Jammer's [Concepts of Space](http://www.amazon.com/Concepts-Space-History-Theories-Enlarged/dp/0486271196/ref=asap_bc?ie=UTF8), [Concepts of Mass](http://www.amazon.com/Concepts-Mass-Classical-Modern-Physics/dp/0486299988/ref=pd_bxgy_14_img_y), and [Concepts of Force](http://www.amazon.com/Concepts-Force-Dover-Books-Physics/dp/048640689X/ref=pd_bxgy_14_img_z).

Comment: Are you interested in Newton's laws only or in the contemporary state of the art? [Robert Hooke: tertentennial studies](https://books.google.fr/books?id=P0-XfTTcwwQC&pg=PA3&lpg=PA3&dq=hooke+kepler%27s+motion&source=bl&ots=zQ21LffJFE&sig=tqnc9XWCk6PWCmuVnOfjPUzl2xo&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=8UaIVdOvIYypsAGUyaLIAQ&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=hooke%20kepler's%20motion&f=false) gives a nice perspective

Comment: Thanks everybody for the suggestions. Hugely appreciated.

Comment: This is a late comment (you've probably far ahead of the gathering info stage), but perhaps reading Euler's Mechanica would prove useful. Its structured very similar to Newton's principia, and is an exposition on classical mechanics, but uses analytical techniques instead of solely geometric ones as Newton does.